# How To Cancel Firebase Query in Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How would you cancel a firebase query? For instance, I have two functions. In functionOne I retrieve data from Firebase Firestore. In functionTwo, I'd like to be able to cancel the retrieval process if the user hits "Cancel."

In other words, I don't want the retrieval process going on in the background still when the user cancels. I want it **terminated**. How can I do this?

Thanks!

I couldn't find anything on the internet about this so far.

Comment: Can you explain what the use case is here? What kind of query would give the user time to start a query and then have the time to actually hit 'cancel'. Also, there may be some options "abort" a query but we would need to understand how your query is structured. Can you update the question with more details and some code so we can fully understand what you're doing?

Comment: Well when the user clicks a certain button it takes them to a table view that loads (reads) data from Firebase. I'm trying to find away that if while it's showing the loading screen (while fetching the data) they click Cancel, it cancels the query and doesn't fill the table view controller with the data and user Reads (you have a limited number before charged extra... as you're aware).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a way to cancel the query after it's been sent. All you can do at that point is detach the `onSnapshot` listener to stop receiving further updates.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen We use pagination and cursors to simulate 'canceling' a query and it works pretty well.

Comment: That's an awesome approach Jay! Upvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you have a large data set - in those cases, loading it all in at one time can overwhelm the device and cause your app to crash.

The solution is to use [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to control the amount of data that's loaded.

While that's the main purpose of paginating your data, it also very useful when you want to give control the user and the ability to 'cancel' a query.

Simply put, if your dataset is 100,000 documents, use pagination to load in 1000 at a time and in between incrementing the pagination cursor, check to see if the user has clicked cancel.

That will be seamless to the user and will cancel when they click cancel.

This technique also enables you to add a loading bar or other indicator to the UI showing how much data has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to cancel a Firestore query once it's been started. As in: once the initial query has been sent to the server, there's no way to stop the server from executing it.

But you can stop receiving further updates by [detaching any listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) from the queries.